# css not getting added to wordpress page even after enqueing it

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to access my custom CSS on my WordPress page by enqueuing it, but the CSS is not getting added I have crossed check by putting the same CSS in built in editor of WordPress it just works there fabulously.

[I'm using astra theme and here is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkyUL.png)
I'm trying to enqueue the CSS i.e., present in child theme.

In CSS file I have added at the top

```
/*
Theme Name:Astra Child
Template:astra
*/
```

and after it the custom CSS and in functions file I'm enqueuing it by

```
<?php
function my_child_theme_scripts() {
    // Enqueue child theme stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sidebar-cdn-icons', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );
```

I am trying to access my custom CSS on my WordPress page by enqueuing it, but the CSS is not getting added I have crossed check by putting the same CSS in built in editor of WordPress it just works there fabulously.

Comment: Can you please include your child-theme-style header comment?  Also, is the child theme your active theme?

Comment: Try registering the stylesheet via `wp_register_style()` before you enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_style()`. More info: [wp_register_style() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/)